# Create a wordpress update query with an associative array done by a for or foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create an associative array by a loop to add it in a update. The problem i have is that i dont know how to go through each element of the 2 arrays for creating an associative array to put in the update query.

You can see down here i put the array inside another array in the update query but its wrong.

I have the following as an example:

```
$table = 'name';
$data = [$_POST['eleicons'], $_POST['elepro'], $_POST['elefont'], $_POST['eleanimations']];
$names = ['eleicons', 'elepro', 'elefont', 'eleanimations'];
$counter = 0;
update($table,
array(
foreach($name as $one => $dat){
$one => $dat[$counter],
$counter++;
}),
array('id' => 0));
```

The array is associative as i said. The update function should look like that:

```
update($table,
array(
$name[0] => $data[0],
$name[1] => $data[1],
$name[2] => $data[2],
$name[3] => $data[3],
),
array('id' => 0));
```

But i would like to do that way:

```
update($table,
$array_associative,
array('id' => 0));
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code you tried? Please edit your question to include an example of the array you are trying to create and details of the problem/error you are getting, so we know what you need and are able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, thanks for the advice. I did change the question. I hope is clear now

Comment: Thanks for updating, but you still haven't told us what the array *should* look like. It's difficult to show you how to create it when we don't know what it is meant to be :)

Comment: ok @FluffyKitten. Now i think is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an associative array from your `$names` and `$data` like this:

```
$count = sizeof($names);    // Get the number of elements in the arrays
// for each element, add the name as the key and the data as the value:
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    $associative_array[$names[$i]] = $data[$i];
```

That will create an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [eleicons] => icons data
    [elepro] => pro data
    [elefont] => font data
    [eleanimations] => animations data
)
```

You can see the output here (using dummy data of course): https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68c5f0a92b33625c437e4c5b9ef17c6f9b2ec4bb

Alternatively, as you are using the `$_POST`, you could create your array this:

```
foreach($names as $key)
    $associative_array[$key] = $_POST[$key];
```

The whole code would then be:

```
$table = 'name';
$names = array('eleicons', 'elepro', 'elefont', 'eleanimations');    
$associative_array = array();

foreach($names as $key)
    $associative_array[$key] = $_POST[$key];

update($table,
       $associative_array,
       array('id' => 0));
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

You are using `table` and `update` in your code, so if you are adding this into a database, you should sanitize any user-provided data before adding it to you DB, otherwise you are wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @ AlvaroGarcia Did this work for you or do you need more help? If it is still not working, let me know what the problem is so I can update the solution. If this answer as useful, you should consider accepting it by checking the grey checkbox beside it - it marks the question as solved on the site and lets other users know it might help them too. Plus you get a few rep points :)